# Can i be taller after 23 and how to gain muscles

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training, yoga, gymnastics

i am 23 years .I want to be taller,on this age i cant get be taller?I would like only six inches.I dont want to wear shoes or anything to make me seem like i am taller.My body can obtain 6 inches or little  more ?If it can be which exercises you suggest me about this age?Second, i lift small weights 11 on each hand(i make 4-5 reps to 20) i make my biceps too.I also do and flexion for chest.Anyway,i dont eat sugar too much i eat healthy and i will describe what i eat now.The morning i do this and after  i eat quaker,honey,milk,eggs,apple,bannana,peanut butter,cornflakes,Orange juice rarely(eggs not everyday,one day i eat the second i dont,that what they told me i dont know if it good or not).After i eat what home has,it can have chicken or spinach,pasticcio,spaghetti,gumbo,lentil and much more but not fast foods.Vegetables like broccoli too.Evening i eat what it was having for lunch sometimes cornflakes and yogurt.The worst i eat is pizza 1 time on 2 weeks.Conclusion,my question is combine both.If i 23 year make this gym exercises(lifting this weight to build muscle) i stop my growing taller(if it can be obtain some extra inches)?if it could be "easy" to you to give me information what exercises can i do to get taller.Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but gave up mid way. Can you be a little more specific about what you want to do, other than increasing height?

Comment: I  lift  11 pounds on each hand for biceps.I make 5 on twoentys .Lets say if i am going to take an inch i would lose and this with that workout?

Comment: How much do you weigh, and how tall are you?

Comment: Your post is rambling and disjoint.  You should pick one or two points as the basis of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you gain height after puberty? **No.**

Can you gain height through exercise? **No.**

Your bone structure determines your height and after puberty has passed, that is fixed. Get used to being the height you are, accept and embrace it. I'm 5ft 4in and I think its great.

As for exercises to build muscle, do compound barbell movements building up to heavy weight with a linear progression (add 2.5lbs every time you go to the gym), go for 5 sets of 5:

- Barbell Squat
- Barbell Deadlift
- Barbell Bench Press
- Barbell Overhead Press
- Barbell Row

If you want to add some accessories to your barbell work, consider:

- Ab work (ab-wheel, hanging leg raises, planks
- Pull/Chin Ups
- Dips

Note: To measure progress, invest in a tape measure and properly measure yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) i would like to tell me if this article is lying too http://www.wikihow.com/Grow-Taller-Overnight

Comment: Doing the above exercises along with the advice in that wikihow will help you achieve your full natural height by developing your core and improving posture. Clothes can also help make you appear taller. The rest is just good life advice. None of those things actually increase your max achievable height.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an inch at 23 is very unlikely, 6 inches naturally is impossible unless your body undergo some hormonal imbalance(which does more harm than good). At around 17-18 you reach almost 99% of your height. Any extra increase won't be noticeable. Whoever tells you otherwise, is selling lies or just trying to sell you some marketing scam. Just accept it and focus on getting and staying fit.

Comment: maybe in 23 i  will not take.In the age on 18 unti 21 i get more than 10 inch (i could say and much more) with not make an exercise for to heigh i didnt wanted to but for sure i take 10inch. I would listen and more aspects.I respect yours but its falsed this( i mean 99.99%)

Comment: Between ages 18-21 you added 10 inches? Well, I don't believe in that claim unless you have evidence to prove it.

Comment: except from the mirror was to small   i mean that i was very very small i couldnt more than heigh from the mirror i had. Also, my  head  was down from the  top of a mirror((which we still having and now).My head is now more than the mirror. My head  was equal with the  lips from my father and now i am more heigh from him.I think 3 inches at least i am taller